# Why request not throw error when timeout?

Tags: node.js, request

I'm using request package and add timeout for it:

```
request.get(link, {
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    timeout,
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    ///
  });
```

But when config timeout under 15000 ms, system throw ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error, but over it, request bypass this timeout. I don't know what wrong at here?

Comment: add if(error) throw error

Comment: it not work in this case, request keep bypass and not throw any error